# Multiindex dataframe rows replacement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Multi-indexed DataFrames.
One is my reference (about 37000 rows) and the other has fewer rows (e.g., 10).

I want to replace the rows of the big one with the values from the second one.

Sample `df1`:

```
lvl1    lvl2 lvl3   Value   Value2

A       1   I   0,862877333 0,181795348
        1   II  0,787022218 0,292046262
        1   III 0,40516176  0,445079108
        2   I   0,882167166 0,683954412
        2   IV  0,743618024 0,103097267
        3   I   0,901062673 0,729188996
        3   II  0,529989452 0,715379923
        3   IV  0,740272198 0,792457421
B       1   I   0,548587694 0,637462653
        1   II  0,201284924 0,084391963
        2   I   0,999118031 0,558207224
        2   II  0,63353019  0,251377184
        2   V   0,694294638 0,685050861
        3   V   0,436723389 0,310871641
        3   VI  0,630832871 0,869957421
        3   VII 0,157874482 0,639308814
```

Sample `df 2`:

```
lvl1    lvl2    lvl3    Value   Value2
A       1       I       0,8654  1
B       2       II      0,264   2
```

Resulting `df3`:

```
lvl1    lvl2 lvl3   Value   Value2

A       1   I   **0,8654**  0,181795348
        1   II  0,787022218 0,292046262
        1   III 0,40516176  0,445079108
        2   I   0,882167166 0,683954412
        2   IV  0,743618024 0,103097267
        3   I   0,901062673 0,729188996
        3   II  0,529989452 0,715379923
        3   IV  0,740272198 0,792457421
        1   I   0,548587694 0,637462653
B       1   II  0,201284924 0,08439196
        2   I   0,999118031 0,558207224
        2   II  **0,264**   0,251377184
        2   V   0,694294638 0,685050861
        3   V   0,436723389 0,310871641
        3   VI  0,630832871 0,869957421
        3   VII 0,157874482 0,639308814
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to replace values on index matching like this:

```
for ind in df2.index:
    df1.loc[ind, 'Value'] = df2.loc[ind, 'Value']
```

If you like to replace rows:

```
for ind in df2.index:
    df1.loc[ind,] = df2.loc[ind,]
```

Comment: This way with the .loc is relly efficient ! no complicated merging nor column drop !

Comment: I used your 2nd code to replace rows, it worked in one PC but on another PC, it has Traceback:  tuple index out of range

Comment: To replace individual values, `at[...]` may be faster than `loc[...]`.  If you're only replacing a few values it won't make much difference, but on my machine replacing 50,000 values was 6 or 7 times slower using `loc` than using `at`.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use `pd.merge`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
temp = pd.DataFrame({"lvl1": ["A","A","B","B"], "lvl2": [1,2,1,2], "lvl3":  ["I","II","I","II"], "Value": [0.8628773,0.7870, 0.63353, 0.6998]})
replace = pd.DataFrame({"lvl1": ["A","B"], "lvl2": [1,2], "lvl3": ["I","II"], "Value": [0.8654, 0.264], "Value2": [1,2]})
df = pd.merge(temp, replace, how="left", on=["lvl1","lvl2","lvl3"])
df["Value_x"] = np.where(df["Value_y"].notnull(), df["Value_y"], df["Value_x"])
# df.drop(["Value_y", "Value2"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I tryed merge (and lookup to join append...) it add a new colum instead of replacing the Value in the original df

Comment: it adds 2 columns, then you just need to replace values using `np.where` as mentioned. If you want to delete these columns use `pd.drop`

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
df1.update(df2['Value'])
```

or if you want to replace all the columns,

```
df1.update(df2)
```

Note that unlike many data frame operations, this works in-place – it modifies df1 instead of returning a copy.